# Isothermal compressibility

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

How does one get from the thermodynamics definition :

$$ \chi_T = -\frac{1}{V} \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T$$

to the fluid dynamics definition :

$$ \chi_T = \frac{1}{\rho} \left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}\right)_T$$

?

Comment: Have you thought about what you could do to the equation to turn all your $V$'s into $\rho$'s?

Comment: I have, and I didn't find the answer to that (that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Have you considered using an ideal gas and proving the relation is true?

Comment: Do you know the relationship between mass, density and volume?

Comment: Well I know that, dimensionally speaking, density is a mass by unit volume. But I get confused because density used to be defined as $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$ and now in Fluid Mechanics I often see $\rho = \frac{dm}{d^3r}$ so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to manipulate this.

Comment: There's really nothing physics based going on in these definitions. It's completely algebra. If you know the definition of density then you should be able to see how to convert from one to the other.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\rho} \left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}\right)_T = \frac{V}{m} \left(\frac{\partial \left(\frac{m}{V}\right)}{\partial p}\right)_T$$  What am I supposed to do from here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the same thing, here is the solution :

$$\begin{align}m &= \rho V = \textrm{constant}\\ \Leftrightarrow~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \rho~\mathrm  dV + V~\mathrm d\rho &= 0\\\Leftrightarrow~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{\mathrm d\rho}{\rho} &= -~ \frac{\mathrm dV}{V}\\\Leftrightarrow~~~~ \chi_T = - ~\frac{1}{V} \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T &= \frac{1}{\rho} \left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}\right)_T\end{align}$$

It's simple but not obvious if you don't know where to start...